# HTTP通信で処理がバックグラウンドに移行してしまう為、データを正しく取得できないのを改善したい。代替案でも?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7

下記の関数は、バックグラウンド処理の関係で、動作順序が変わってしまい、関数の返り値が、予定したものにならない。

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest.....
```

この行以降が飛ばされ、関数が終了する。

改善方法を教えていただけないでしょうか？
Postを利用するため、この方法になっています。代替案でもいいです。

コードが古すぎていたので、HTTPアドレス以外、正しく動くように修正いたしました。

下記の場合、printの出力順が、"NG"->HTMLコードとなる。正しくはHTMLコード->"OK"となってほしい。

よろしく、お願いいたします。

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController ,NSURLSessionDelegate, NSURLSessionDataDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    print(Test())
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func Test()-> String{
    let post = "name=Masuda&addr=Tokyo"
    let postdata = post.dataUsingEncoding(NSShiftJISStringEncoding)!
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://moonmile.net/ios9/post.php")
    let req = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
    req.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    req.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    let length = postdata.length
    req.setValue("\(length)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    req.HTTPBody = postdata
    var textBuf : String = "NG"
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(req, completionHandler: {
        ( data, res, err ) in
        if data != nil {

            let text = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSShiftJISStringEncoding)

            print(NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSShiftJISStringEncoding))
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                textBuf = "OK"
            })
        }
    })

    task.resume()
    return textBuf
}
}
```

Comment: while (waiting) {
            NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().runMode(NSDefaultRunLoopMode, beforeDate: NSDate())
        }
追加して、動作しました。自己解決しました。

Comment: [自己解決された場合は、自分で回答を追加](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/1747/30)して質問を解決済みにしておくと、ステータスが分かりやすくなります。また、回答を見つけた他の人が喜ぶかもしれません。 // いずれにせよ解決してよかったです

Answer (score 3):

非同期処理の結果がすぐに得られないからといって、「終了待ちをする」というのは誤った解決方法です。単純ループで終了待ちをするのはもってのほかですが、今回の例のようにメインスレッドから呼ばれる想定のメソッド内で不特定の時間待ち続けると、メインスレッドの処理が停滞して、ユーザビリティーを損ないますので、絶対にやめてください。

非同期処理を利用するコードを書く場合には、以下の原則を覚えておくと良いでしょう。
1. 非同期処理を起動するメソッドからは処理の結果は返せない
2. 非同期処理を起動したら、そのメソッドの中ではもう何もしない
3. 非同期処理の結果は必ず完了ハンドラーの中で処理する

実際のアプリの場合には、単にStringの中身をprintするだけ、ということは考えられないので、汎用のメソッドにしたいと言うことであれば、結果を戻り値として返すのではなく、結果を引数として渡すような完了ハンドラーを自前のメソッドにも持たせるというのが一つの方法です。

ご提示いただいた元の例をそのように書き直してみると、こんな感じになります。

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController ,NSURLSessionDelegate, NSURLSessionDataDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        Test({(result: String)->Void in //非同期処理の結果は必ず完了ハンドラーの中で処理する
            print(result)
        })
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func Test(completionHandler: (String)->Void) { //自前のメソッドにも完了ハンドラーを持たせる
        let post = "name=Masuda&addr=Tokyo"
        let postdata = post.dataUsingEncoding(NSShiftJISStringEncoding)!
        let url = NSURL(string: "http://moonmile.net/ios9/post.php")
        let req = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
        req.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        req.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        //HTTPBodyをNSDataで指定する場合、Content-Lengthの設定は不要
        req.HTTPBody = postdata
        var textBuf : String = "NG"
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(req, completionHandler: {
            ( data, res, err ) in
            if data != nil {

                let text = String(data: data!, encoding: NSShiftJISStringEncoding)

                print(text)
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    textBuf = "OK"
                    completionHandler(textBuf) //完了ハンドラーの中で自前の完了ハンドラーを呼ぶ
                })
            }
        })
        task.resume()
        //非同期処理を起動した後は、そのメソッドの中では何もしない
    }
}
```

ボタンが押された後に何かの処理をする、という場合に`while !isButtonPressed {/*...*/}`といった具合にループでボタンが押されるのを待つと言った書き方は(iOS等のプログラムでは)見たことがないと思います。(大昔のワンボードマイコンのプログラミングでは普通にやってましたが…。)通信を伴う非同期処理の場合にも、処理を待ち合わせてつじつまを合わせるのではなく、きちんとした非同期処理のパターンを身につけてください。

Comment: 遅くなってすみません。書いていただいたコードですが、『Test({(result: String)->Void in』のところと、『completionHandler(textBuf)』でエラーが出てしまい、実行できません。理解できていないので、改善もできません。何か改善方法や解説などのありかなど、教えていただけないでしょうか？よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 通信先をテスト用のサーバに置き換えた以外は、最新のXcodeでコンパイル／実行時ともにエラーが出ないのを確認してからコードを掲載していますので、「エラーが出てしまい、実行できません」だけでは情報が足りません。どのようなエラーなのかもう少し詳しくお教えください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。まっさらのプロジェクトにコピーしたらエラー起きませんでした。こちら側の手違いのようです。すみませんでした。これから解析して組み込みます。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 勘違いは回答を書き込む側にもありえますから、よくわからない点があればコメント等でご確認いただくのは当然かと思います。実アプリに使う通信処理となるとエラー処理やタイムアウト処理なども必要ですし、通信の完了待ちの間どのような画面にするか、キャンセル可能にするのか等々大変なところが色々出てきます。お示ししたコードから拡張していくことが可能かと思いますので、頑張ってみてください。

Answer (score -3):

以下のコードが解決後のコードです。

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController ,NSURLSessionDelegate, NSURLSessionDataDelegate {

    var waiting = true //追加

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        print(Test())
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func Test()-> String{
        let post = "name=Masuda&addr=Tokyo"
        let postdata = post.dataUsingEncoding(NSShiftJISStringEncoding)!
        let url = NSURL(string: "http://moonmile.net/ios9/post.php")
        let req = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
        req.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        req.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        let length = postdata.length
        req.setValue("\(length)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
        req.HTTPBody = postdata
        var textBuf : String = "NG"
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(req, completionHandler: {
            ( data, res, err ) in
            if data != nil {

                let text = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSShiftJISStringEncoding)

                print(NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSShiftJISStringEncoding))
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    textBuf = "OK"
                    waiting = false //追加
                })
            }
        })

        task.resume()
        //追加
        while (waiting) {
            NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().runMode(NSDefaultRunLoopMode, beforeDate: NSDate())
        }
        return textBuf
    }
}
```

Comment: 今更感がありますが、あまりにも酷い回答なのでコメントしておきます。この回答のようにフラグを使って非同期処理の終了待ちをするなんてことは絶対に避けるべきです。たとえ`NSRunLoop`を使って見かけ上UIスレッドがブロックしていないように見せかけようと、こんなコードでは「一体何が起こるのかわからない」状態になってしまいます。このメソッドを呼んだ時にイベントループに入っているイベントは処理されますか、タスクの完了までに新たにイベントループに入ってきたイベントは全て正しく処理されますか?Appleの`NSRunLoop`のドキュメントにはそんなことは書いてくれていません。そもそもこんな使い方は想定外だからです。他に方法がないのであれば、ドキュメント外の「現在の動作」に依存して処理を書かなければ仕方ないこともあるかもしれませんが、完了ハンドラーパターンで簡単に実装できることをなぜこのような不確実なやり方に書き換える必要があるのでしょうか?